# Hard drive is working fine then next boot up shows up as a unformatted

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery

The drive is a Samsung Spinpoint F3 HD103SJ 1TB.

There are no SMART errors and the drive sounds healthy.

Restarted the computer from the drive working fine and then noticed that the drive had the same drive letter but has RAW as the file system.

I have a few file/partition recovery software titles available but since doing any scans on this drive takes about 2.5 hours I wanted to know if any one had any advice.

Comment: Try a new Sata data cable.

Comment: Tried two different SATA cables, different motherboard, and a SATA to USB adapter. Same results every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow.. the problem was the entire drive was encrypted with trucrypt. Loaded the drive up with truecrypt with the password and it mounted fine.